# Problem with requests.get() inside a loop. "No connection adapters found"

Tags: python, loops, python-requests, web-crawler

So I'm trying to scrape several pages using their JSON versions. When I run the code for a single URL (as in the first part of the code attached), I do get the desired output, however, when I try to do the same inside a for loop for several URLs, I get a "No connection adapters found" from requests, which doesn't make much sense because it is working for the same URL outside of the for loop.

```
# Import package
import requests
from pandas import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

# Assign URL to variable: url
url = 'https://www.olx.com.gt/api/relevance/search?category=367&facet_limit=100&location=4168811&location_facet_limit=20&page=1&sorting=desc-creation&user=16c20011d0fx61aada41'

# Package the request, send the request and catch the response: r
r = requests.get(url)

# Decode the JSON data into a dictionary: json_data
json_data = r.json()

# Extract data from the Json file
json_data_2 = json_data['data']

#normalize json data into a dataframe
df = json_normalize(json_data_2)
df.head()
```

Everything runs smoothly with this script. Here's where I get the error.

```
%%time

n_paginas = 0

all_urls = pd.DataFrame()

for paginas in range(0,20):
    n_paginas += 1
    olx_url = 'https://www.olx.com.gt/api/relevance/search?category=367&facet_limit=100&location=4168811&location_facet_limit=20&page=%s&sorting=desc-creation&user=16c20011d0fx61aada41'
    start_urls = [olx_url % n_paginas]
    r = requests.get(start_urls)
    #json_data = r.json()
    #json_data_2 = json_data['data']
    #df = json_normalize(json_data_2)
    #all_urls.apped(df)
```

And this is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidSchema                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     74 
     75     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 76     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     77 
     78 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    528         }
    529         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 530         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 
    532         return resp

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    635 
    636         # Get the appropriate adapter to use
--> 637         adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
    638 
    639         # Start time (approximately) of the request

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in get_adapter(self, url)
    726 
    727         # Nothing matches :-/
--> 728         raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
    729 
    730     def close(self):

InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.olx.com.gt/api/relevance/search?category=367&facet_limit=100&location=4168811&location_facet_limit=20&page=1&sorting=desc-creation&user=16c20011d0fx61aada41']"
```

The new URLs based on the page number are being generated correctly, and if I input any of them on the script above it does work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need the `start_urls = [olx_url % n_paginas]` part. Either way this slight modification to the for loop seemed to get the result.

```
# Import package
import requests
from pandas import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

# Assign URL to variable: url
url = 'https://www.olx.com.gt/api/relevance/search?category=367&facet_limit=100&location=4168811&location_facet_limit=20&page=1&sorting=desc-creation&user=16c20011d0fx61aada41'

# Package the request, send the request and catch the response: r
r = requests.get(url)

# Decode the JSON data into a dictionary: json_data
json_data = r.json()

# Extract data from the Json file
json_data_2 = json_data['data']

#normalize json data into a dataframe
df = json_normalize(json_data_2)
df.head()

n_paginas = 0

all_urls = pd.DataFrame()

for paginas in range(0,20):
    n_paginas += 1
    olx_url = 'https://www.olx.com.gt/api/relevance/search?category=367&facet_limit=100&location=4168811&location_facet_limit=20&page={}&sorting=desc-creation&user=16c20011d0fx61aada41'.format(str(n_paginas))
    r = requests.get(olx_url)
    all_urls = all_urls.append(pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(r.json()['data'])))

all_urls.shape

(400, 60)
```

Comment: That's very odd. But you are right, that was the problem. Thank you so much Joe!